# HHL algorithm, How can I get result from register $|b\rangle$?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation

From the paper [A survey on HHL algorithm: From theory to application in quantum machine learning](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S037596012030462X?token=341DFB233CC9E10AE9650DF6683807615693ADE6B9F4A8F400F594A1487EDA46868B04B6130D3ACD38282B91943A2F79) ,
I use qasm code from [here](https://github.com/dreamingangela/ibmq_hhl/blob/master/hhl.qasm/).
I try to follow the example in page 7. with Ax = b
[image: matrix A] 
and 
[image] 
the answer x should be
[image]

From the algorithm 2 in page 7 from the paper, They applied measurement on qubit q[0]. 
If  q[0] = $|1\rangle$, the answer will be stored in q[.3] or register b.

[image: HHL circuit from page 7]

But in the example [here](https://github.com/dreamingangela/ibmq_hhl/blob/master/hhl.qasm/), I got state $|0\rangle$ from ancilla bit if I use the same rotation angle as the example.

When I measure register b, I always got  state $|1\rangle$  even if the result on ancilla bit is $|1\rangle$ (I change ancilla bit rotation angel from the example to 3.6591 and 1.8296).

Does the problem is the rotation angle on ancilla bit? 
How can I get the correct result on register b? Can you give me a good example to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In your code the measure clause means one shot, so the state collapses to one basis state as here:
[image]
By removing that last line the Statevector option shows the state before measurement, i.e. as a superposition of basis states:
[image]
Now you can see that for the basis states with `q[0]=1` (that is `0001` and `1001`) we get the right components of the solution vector $x$ (you can check that the numbers coincide with those reported in Table 2, row 1 of the paper you mentioned).

The "right" thing to do here if you want to avoid statevectors would be to do a few measurements and calculate the probabilities of obtaining `0001` and `1001`, which is what they explain in Section 3.3.2. of the paper. The more measurements you do, the closer the probabilities you calculate will be to those from the statevector simulation.